# Transformed integral problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, transformation

I've come across a question where it required an integral, $$I=\int\int_Tdpdq$$Where $0\le p \le 1$, $0\le q \le 1$, is the region $T$ to be mapped onto the region R with transformation:$$p(x)=4x-4x^2, q=y$$ Where $0\le x \le 1$, $0\le y \le 1$ for the region R.

I transformed the integral to get:$$I = \int\int_R(4-8x)dxdy$$
Solving both of these intregrals over their given domains I managed to get:$$I=\int\int_Tdpdq=1$$
and$$I = \int\int_R(4-8x)dxdy=0$$
My question is, why are the two values different? Shouldn't the value be the same after the transformation?
I may have made an error somewhere or is there some explanation for the results obtained?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your second integral cannot be over the same region, as you have changed coordinates. As you did not give the specific limits, it is hard to pinpoint the mistake. Note also that there is a trick here: $p(0) = p(1)$!

Comment: The limits were given as the (p,q) and (x,y) domains from the given question, as such, I set up the integrals as $\int_0^1\int_0^1 dpdq$ and $\int_0^1\int_0^1 (4-8x) dxdy$

Comment: I have edited the problem statement to reflect the true nature of the question

Comment: The image of $T=\{(p,q)\in\mathbb R^2|0\le p\le 1;0\le q\le1\}$ is not $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|0\le x\le 1;0\le y\le1\}$ bu $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|0\le x\le 1/2;0\le y\le1\}$

Comment: So this would account for the discrepancy in my answers

Comment: Undoubtedly. You can calculate the integral for the new limits fr $x,y$ and you get the same result as for $p,q$